# Embedding a RESTful url in email to add a Google Calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-oauth

I'd like to send an email with a link in it which, when clicked, creates a new event on a Google calendar that I've created (and made public).

I've created a project in the Google Developer's Cloud Console, and have api keys, etc.  It's connected to the Calendar API.  But I can't figure out how to do exactly what I want.

The calendar in question is meant to keep track of when and where students want to get together to work on homework problem sets together.  So the emails notify them about what rooms are available at given times.  The links embedded in the emails reserve a given study room/time when clicked (meaning, it adds an event on a Google calendar which specifically stores reservation info).

I've gotten a bit lost in REST and OAuth documentation for Google Apps; I've tried a number of different strategies but so far none have worked very well - so I'm hesitant to post any of my failed code attempts.  I've tried playing around with the OAuth2 playground that Google provides, but I'm not quite sure how to put the json it provides together with a call to the Calendar API, all in one URI.

One issue is that OAuth is basically meant to acquire permission from the user to access their stuff.  But in this case, it's not the user (ie. email recipient) that needs to give permission for anything.  By clicking the link in the email, it's /my/ calendar they'd be changing (which, while public, isn't a calendar they're necessarily shared on).

So ideally I'd be able to embed some kind of authorization to make these changes within the link they click, so that they never have to see any of the OAuth side of things, or be bothered by extra prompts.  The ideal application flow is simply: get email with available times, click link, receive note that reservation has been added to the calendar.  (With an invite to join that calendar, perhaps)

I've nosed around on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530092/how-to-add-event-on-other-user-calendar-without-being-logged-in?rq=1) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282162/google-calendar-api-how-to-create-edit-delete-events-without-google-password) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114233/adding-calendar-event-to-specific-calendar) and get the sense that this can be done, but there just hasn't been enough example code for me to go off of, and the documentation, while helpful to my understanding, doesn't seem to provide me with the starting point I'm looking for.

If anyone has an example URI, including all parameters/paths needed to clear OAuth and insert a new event in the calendar, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't create an event through a link because the API required a http post action and with the link you will do only a get.
Alternative, you can create an ICS invite and send as attachment to your guests. 
See the example bellow:

```
function sendInvites() {
  var startDate = new Date(2013,11,26, 10,0);
  var endDate = new Date(2013, 11, 26, 10,30);
  var guestMail = "mymail@mymail.com";


  var event = CalendarApp.createEvent(eventTitle, startDate, endDate);
  event.setTitle("Event Title");
  event.setDescription("My description");
  event.setLocation("My Location");


  //OR
  //var event = CalendarApp.getEventSeriesById("event id");


var ics = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nPRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar     70.9054//EN\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
ics+= "DTSTART:"+Utilities.formatDate(startDate, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'")
    +"\r\nDTEND:"+Utilities.formatDate(endDate, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'")+"\r\n";
ics+= "UID:"+event.getId()+"\r\n";
ics+= "SUMMARY:"+event.getTitle()+"\r\nLOCATION:"+event.getLocation()+"\r\nDESCRIPTION:\r\n";
ics+= "SEQUENCE:0\r\nSTATUS:CONFIRMED\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR\r\n";


MailApp.sendEmail(guestMail, "invite", "invite body",  {attachments: [Utilities.newBlob(ics, "text/calendar")]});
}
```

live version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1iwtitwxo_1Xnw0kLOjkxJYTyg0doMwxnTFL_NYteaRSnNVRrUHJOkudU/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.  However I don't want to create an event and then send an attachment - the email itself lists a number of possible times to reserve a room/time, and the recipient has to select one in order to create the event.  If I created all the events beforehand, it'd be as if they'd already reserved all the possible openings. I did notice that the insert method is POST, not GET.  As such I tried embedded an html form in the email, with the POST parameters included as hidden elements. That's when I ran into authorization issues.  Is there solution with an embedded form?

Comment: I guess that you will face some problems like storing the token value. Why don't you create a form inside apps script and put their link in the mail?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure I'm following you.  I did generate all the email content within an apps script, and then the email they get just shows a button to click.  But you're right, it's the token I'm trying to get around.  Is a token strictly necessary with a public calendar?